# How do i pass Env variales to a spark job?

Tags: apache-spark

In my Envelope pipeline, I need to compare two Hive tables. Instead of hardcoding the tables in the .conf file, I would like to pass which tables I'm going to compare. I tried using spark.yarn.appMaster.varName but it doesn't seem to work. I'm running CDH 5.13.3 with Java 1.8 on a Centos VM.

This is what the script that runs the spark job looks like:

```sh
#!bin/bash

sudo -u hdfs spark2-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.tableA=dbA.tableA \
  --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.tableB=dbB.tableB \
  envelope-0.7.2.jar comparison.conf
```

Part of my .conf file:

```
application{name = comparison}

steps {

  tableA {    
    type = hive    
    table = ${tableA}    
  }

  tableB {    
    type = hive    
    table = ${tableB}
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part "appMaster.Env" incorrect, "appMasterEnv" have to be used:

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.tableA=dbA.tableA
```

Details can be found here:
[Running Spark on YARN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)